# Google sheets query sum total between two dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this.

```
2020-04-25  63
2020-04-26  34
2020-04-27  12
2020-04-28  33
2020-04-29  45
2020-04-30  10
2020-05-01  34
2020-05-02  12
2020-05-03  45
2020-05-04  18
2020-05-05  45
2020-05-06  21
2020-05-07  34
2020-05-08  56
2020-05-09  21
```

Is it possible to use a google sheets query to sum the total between two dates, between 2020-05-01 and 2020-05-05 the total would be 154?

I understand it's possible to search greater than / less than dates, but unsure how to sum the returned total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming dates in column A, try

```
=query(A2:B, "Select sum(B) where A >= date '2020-05-01' and A <= date '2020-05-05' label sum(B)''", 0)
```

Or, using sumproduct:

```
=sumproduct(A2:A>=date(2020, 5, 1), A2:A<=date(2020, 5, 5), B2:B)
```

or, using sumifs:

```
=sumifs(B2:B, A2:A, ">="&date(2020, 5, 1), A2:A, "<="&date(2020, 5, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B, A1:A, ">="&DATEVALUE("2020-05-01"), 
              A1:A, "<="&DATEVALUE("2020-05-05"))
```

[image]